# Java - 2 threads finished executing, 2 other threads are waiting for a condition but i cannot signal those conditions from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

basically I have 4 threads running.

After 2 threads are done executing the other 2 threads should go back and continue executing too.

The problem is that the last 2 threads (3 && 4) finish execution whilst threads 1 and 2 just sit there waiting and I don't know how to set them back into a runnable state from thread 4.

Comment: Trying to signal the condition to start running while my current thread is not the same as the previous ones gives me an external monitor error.

Comment: you can't set "them back". once a thread is done - it's done. You might want to use a pool, that works differently with threads

Comment: I am unfortunately not allowed to use a threadpool with this specific task :/

Comment: in such a case the only option you have is spawn new threads

Comment: Well that sure is a shame

Comment: @Lamebro1 all thread would execute the same task or different tasks?

Comment: 1 thread is a "storage thread" and the other is a work thread. There is a set of jobs which need x number of storage threads and x number of work threads. so lets say a job with 2 storage threads and 2 work threads should wait until there are 2 of each (4 in total) then run the "job" using those threads @dreamcrash

Comment: Currently what happens is lets say 2 work threads are started (so no 2 store threads) then 2 store threads are started so there is enough for the job. The 2 store threads recognize this and start so now the job only has the 2 work threads left, but the 2 workthreads are still there waiting to go.

Comment: is the problem that you want threads 1,2 to run and threads 3,4 wait til 1,2 are done, and once 3 and 4 run 1,2 wait until 3,4 are done, and continue like that ad infinitum?

Comment: The problem is more like i want threads 1 and 2 to run along 3 and 4, but threads 1 and 2 cannot run until 3 and 4 are started.

If i had a 5th thread, a part of the 1 and 2 family, and I start it after 3 and 4 then the program will run, but otherwise the threads 1 and 2 will never go back to actually executing

Comment: I'd suggest to add the code as the problem is not stated clearly from the question neither from these comments.

Comment: I added the relevant piece of code in question. The idea is the first group of threads call the first function and vice versa

Comment: I see two locks, which leads me to believe with the code you shown that is a classic case of dead lock, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock
"Both processes need resources to continue execution. P1 requires additional resource R1 and is in possession of resource R2, P2 requires additional resource R2 and is in possession of R1; neither process can continue."
the problem with the code is that it's not clear how you start your threads and the locks that you use per thread. more code will make it easier to understand

Comment: Ill look into deadlock, might potentially be it.

I was worried that if i oly use one lock then the threads won't actually run together.

Comment: I think you will be better of stating the problem that you want to solve, I see multiple hints that the code is not thread safe (jobList for starters is not thread safe and more than one job updates it) at all and is a long discussion. Unless you state your problem diferently you will not receive good help

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive enough

Basically we create a "job" and start x number "compute" threads and x amount of "storage threads" when the neccesary amounts of threads are started

Comment: When theres enoug threads the threads "do the task" @LuisRamirez-Monterosa